# Audit the /token API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Using MVC5 ASP.NET WebAPI2 and there is a default token API named /token that is used for authentication. I would like to audit the access to this API i.e. the IP address etc. from where it is accessed etc., how could this be accomplished?

Comment: Are you using OWIN. If so you can create a middle ware to monitor that path and then log its flow through the pipeline.